# after_touch callback is fired multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a hierarchy of models, for which I'm trying to cascade a :touch event.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts

    after_touch :do_stuff

    def do_stuff
        # do stuff...
    end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category, :touch => true
    has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post, :touch => true
end
```

I have a form for Post which creates a new Comment through nesteed_attributes. When this event occurs the after_touch method on the Category class is fired 4 times in quick succession (milliseconds apart) and I'm at a bit of a loss to understand why.

In my minds-eye the callback should only be fired once for the transaction? I also notice that in events such as destroying a post the callback is fired for the post, and each of the comments which is destroyed, resulting in many-many calls.

Is this normal behaviour? Is it expected? Is there a way around this? Is this a bug in Rails?

Comment: maybe you want to use `after_initialize` ?

Comment: Sorry bud - It's Rails 4.0.0, I'll update the tags in a moment.

Comment: after_touch is a callback you want to use? or it's a method you need to apply on object?

Comment: My bad, my code example wasn't right - I've updated it. after_touch is registered as a callback which invokes a method called do_stuff - this method is the one being called multiple times.

Comment: and can you please post logs starting with submit a comment action? or you think there is nothing important?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34847/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-18060735-after-touch-callback-is-fired-multipl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this is 'by design' within Rails at the moment. There also doesn't seem to be any immediate plan to change this, so for the moment if you're planning on using :touch and only require a single callback, you need to look at another option.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8759

Answer (score 3):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts

    after_touch :do_stuff

    def do_stuff
        # do stuff...
    end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end

posts_controller

def update
  ...
  if @post.update
     @post.category.touch
  else
     ...
  end

end
```

Comment: After a long discussion with rmagnum2002 we were unable to determine why the callback was being fired multiple times, no matter how far back we stripped the code

For the moment we have opted to move the touch away from the accociation definition and in to the controller.